# Long running webjob aborts for no reason

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a very long running webjob. I expect it to run in the order of months. From time to time it aborts, usually after on average 3 or 4 days, with no log that I can see of why. The messages in the dashboard say "Never completed" and the job is aborted. CPU timeouts are set to high numbers. What can I do to have a permanently running webjob ?

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to have a permanently running webjob ?

In order to let the WebJob running consistently, please make sure always-on is on. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) for more information. Here is a snippet:

[image]

> CPU timeouts are set to high numbers.

Please also note that there will a 230s limitation in Azure web app. It will also affect trigger WebJob that applies anytime an http request is involved. We could find more detailed information at [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17305ddc-07b2-436c-881b-286d1744c98f/503-errors-with-large-pdf-file?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Because WebJob use the same resources with Web App, please also check the App Service Plan to ensure the memory, CPU are enough for your Web App.

Comment: Thanks. The service is already "Always On". The process aborts anyway. On avg about once every 2 or 3 days.